# jsonwebtoken doesn't retrieve a token

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, json-web-token

I am using nodejs and sequelize to create simple user registration, I already did the login and register, but when login is a success I don't get any token.

I have tried to console.log the token to see if I get some result, but there is no response in the console related to the token.

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var User = require('../../models').User;
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var app = require('../../app');

/*var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
  expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
});*/

router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
  if (JSON.stringify(req.body) == "{}") {
    return res.status(400).json({ Error: "Login request body is empty" });
  }
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ Error: "Missing fields for login" });
  }


  // search a user to login
  User.findOne({ where: { username: req.body.username} }) // searching a user with the same username and password sended in req.body
    .then(function (user) {
      if (user && user.validPassword(req.body.password)) {
        //return res.status(200).json({ message: "loged in!" }); // username and password match

        // create a token
        var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
          expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
        });

        // return the information including token as JSON
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Enjoy your token!',
          token: token
        });
      }
      else{
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" }); // if there is no user with specific fields send
      }
    }).catch(function (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: "server issues when trying to login!" }); // server problems
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You are not able to get response or you are not able to see token in response?

Comment: i don't see the token and it enters in my catch if i have the code to generate the token, strange

Comment: The second parameter you pass to jwt.sign is the secret. I am not sure what you are trying to do with app.get('superSecret'). Also I would advise against passing the entire user-object including passwords into the jwt as you will have access to it in the browser.

Comment: so what should i pass to the jwt.sign, just the id?

Comment: Yes, you should avoid sending the whole user object in payload because it could contain password. If the code is ending in catch then there is a exception, for some reason(s).

Comment: Try debugging like, console the err object in catch block or return the err object in response.

Comment: capitalisation, punctuation and spelling

Answer (score 0):

You should use express-jwt library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt
It's middleware for express. Example:

```
    var jwt = require('express-jwt');

    app.get('/protected',
          jwt({secret: 'shhhhhhared-secret',
               credentialsRequired: false,
               getToken: (req) => req.cookies.id_token // when cookies are using. 'id_token' is cookie's name
    }),
          function(req, res) {
            if (!req.user.admin) return res.sendStatus(401);
            res.sendStatus(200);
          });
```

Also you may write as app.use(...) or app.anyRequest(...)